# Not able to export Highchart "SVG" image in microsoft edge using canvg library

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, canvg

Following code i tried to render and export Highchart SVG Image.
I am able to get image downloaded while I Haven't hovered over my image(while there was no tooltip got added)
[image]

But when i hover over image there is a new  element get added which contains tooltip of highchart. and then I'm unable to export Image through canvg after that. 
[image]

```
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($(rawSVGHTML)[0]);

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        cctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = dimention.width;
        canvas.height = dimention.height;
        cctx.drawSvg(s); //It is a function from Canvg library
```

Comment: Could you reproduce it somehow in online code editor like jsfiddle? Is it not working only on Edge?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel For other browser i created a base64 and appended over it to a link and downloaded through that but as IE support MSToBlob I tried that as well but unfortunately i got blank Image.

Comment: Then I tried Canvg Library, 
Without hover over chart it got exported(As i have mentioned I'm getting a tooltip later after hover over chart).
But when i do it The Canvg throwing an error

Comment: Even i tried removing tooltip div runtime and tried to bind it again after download but It's not worrking through that way.

Comment: And have you considered using Highcharts exporting module? Check here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview, https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/exporting

Comment: Look jsfiddle
 https://jsfiddle.net/hg765s34/11/

Comment: Yup i used all required module and generated chart accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but this map was generated by canvg and not highcharts export, isn't it?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I haven't used highchart export. the problem was with rgbcolor library which was missing before canvg library, so i fixed issue using that lib. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome;)